# Transaction with merchant-managed payment not working in Switzerland anymore

Tags: actions-on-google

Until at least March 1st 2021 it was possible to perform [transactions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-custom) with a Swiss Android device in Switzerland. Support also confirmed that this should still be possible:

> We can confirm that the transaction API is indeed available in Switzerland. However, this issue is not within our scope.

Since this week (March 8th) however this does not work anymore. We did not change anything on our action or backend.
When trying to perform the transaction the action responds with:

> Tut mir leid, aber in deiner Region kann ich keine Zahlungen
> durchführen.

This roughly translates to "Unfortunately, I cannot perform any payments in your region."

**What we've tried**

- We've double-checked that the location targeting is correct and checked the stackdriver logs, which show also that the "transaction requirements check" returned "CAN_TRANSACT" with a swiss location.
- Doing the identical transaction with a (faked) German location instead of Swiss location still works correctly.
- Using another Action which uses the transaction API but does not use merchant-managed payment still works fine with a Swiss location. That other action uses the transaction API without any payment.

So this leads me to believe this is an issue on Google's side that it is not possible anymore to perform merchant-managed payments in Switzerland.